# Userform Combo boxes Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

So kind of annoying because I have tried every suggestion that I have read so far, ut I cannot seem to get my user form combo boxes to be filled via VBA.

I have tried the following methods that seem to work for everyone but me....

```
 Me.Weeks.List = Array("30", "36", "40")
```

And....

```
 With Weeks
     .AddItem "30"
     .AddItem "36"
     .AddItem "40"
 End With
```

And so far nothing shows up in the userform when I run it. Is there a setting I am missing?  Of course these are part of the initialize event. :)

MORE CODE PER REQUEST:

```
 Private Sub ToolBoxForm_Initialize()

Weeks.Clear
'MORE STUFF

Me.MinAYWeeks.List = Array("30", "36", "40")

'With MinAYWeeks
'    .AddItem "30"
'    .AddItem "36"
'    .AddItem "40"
'End With

'MORE STUFF

 End Sub
```

There's also stuff that does calculations with the OK button, but nothing that affects the contents of the combobox, just stuff that references the value of the selected option.

Thanks in advance guys

[image]

Comment: What kind of error message do you get? Show a bit more of your code, it's hard to guess with that little information.

Comment: @Tom I dont get an error message at all. The combo box on the userform doesnt show anything at all. This lead me to think that everything is executing ok, so I sifted through the properties window and messed around with several settings and still nothing. What part of the code would you like to see?

Comment: At least everything related to that combobox :)

Answer (score 2):

In your userform initialize event add your code, but add a reference to the userform (Me.Weeks).

```
With Me.Weeks
 .AddItem "30"
 .AddItem "36"
 .AddItem "40"
End With
```

[image]

Comment: this also does not work, though I did try it previously and again when you suggested it.

Comment: Check out the image I added. Are you sure it is under the UserForm Initialize event? To get there double click within the userform design area and select Userform in the left dropdown at the top and Initialize in the right drop down at the top.

Comment: i also added an image. I think the issue might be due to my having named the userform in the properties window.....

Comment: Funny story. My image gave me the idea to set the combo box contents on multi page change events and that works perfectly. Yet however I cannot get it to trigger from the initialize sub. Weird. I guess functionally its the same in this instance but now I am just curious as to what is causing the issue?